# Function columns cached

Tags: sql-server, caching, user-defined-functions

It looks like `select *` in a UDF is dangerous.  Consider this script:

```
create table TestTable (col1 int, col2 varchar(1))
insert into TestTable values (123, 'a')
go

create function TestFunction
(
    @param1 bit
)
returns table
as
return
(
    select * from TestTable
)
go

select * from TestFunction(0)

alter table TestTable
add col3 varchar(1)

select * from TestFunction(0)

drop function TestFunction
drop table TestTable
go
```

You will get two result sets, both with the same number of columns, even though I added `col3`.  If the table is recreated an an extra column is inserted in the middle, everything will shift one column over, showing the data under the wrong column name.  In other words, the columns will stay the same, but the data has an extra column.

I wasn't able to find any information about this, but it seems to me the only way to avoid this is to always specify your columns in a function.

So my question is, what exactly does a UDF cache?  It seems output columns are--anything else?  Also, any way to still use `select *` but prevent this problem?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function's metadata does not automatically update.  Run an `ALTER` statement.

Comment: Ah, if it's metadata I assume it's stored in one of the system tables?

Comment: @Nelson - Yes, in the base table `sys.syscolpars` (only accessible via the DAC) You can see it in the `sys.columns` view. `select * from sys.columns where object_id=object_id('TestFunction')`

Answer (score 2):

Add `exec sp_refreshsqlmodule 'TestFunction'` before the second call.

Comment: Good answer, though my example was for demonstration purposes.  The real problem is when your app uses that function, then the underlying table changes.  If the function isn't refreshed, your data is all wrong now.

Comment: @Nelson - Yep. And the same issue exists with views. Another reason to avoid `*`!